# Waypoints sticky leaving white space from hidden table

Tags: jquery

We have this call on a page in our system:

```
  var sticky = new Waypoint.Sticky({
    element: $('#graph1')[0],})
```

In the default state of the page will have #Table1 and #Graph2 both hidden this works perfect.

When #Table1 is showing and either #Graph2 hidden or showing this makes the #Graph1 anchor to the top with white space between #Graph1 one and the final desired table. the same size as #Graph2

I have tried adding a Handler on #Graph2 and on the final table but the white space remains and the graph does not release the sticky.

Comment: Resizing the window or opening Chrome dev tools, makes the tables all fall in alignment and work as desired.

Comment: Further looking, it seems that sticky-wrapper is remaining locked and that is the white space.